# ms sql find unicode 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-like

At the database is a unicode 0 written and then a query started to find the value. 
Example:

```
select *,Len(test) as length, Unicode(test) as unicode,DATALENGTH(test) as datalength 
from (values (NCHAR(0x0))) as t(test)
where test like N'_'
```

but the value is not returned. Why? What need I to do that it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected behaviour per the [Pattern matching documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#pattern-matching-with-the-escape-clause):

> 0x0000 (char(0)) is an undefined character in Windows collations and
>   cannot be included in LIKE.

Note, however, that `LIKE CHAR(0)` does work

```
DECLARE @Character nchar(1);
SET @Character = NCHAR(0);
SELECT CASE WHEN @Character LIKE CHAR(0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Or

```
DECLARE @Character nchar(10);
SET @Character = NCHAR(0);
SELECT CASE WHEN @Character LIKE '%' + CHAR(0) + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

Specifically, the documentation is saying that using a wildcard, such as `'_'` for `(N)CHAR(0)` will not work.

Comment: Another consideration to know when using "_" as wild character. +1

Comment: (values (NCHAR(0x0)),(nchar(0xFFFF)) with 0xFFFF it also not works.

Comment: @tire0011 That looks like another undefined character, in all honesty: http://www.alansofficespace.com/unicode/unicd65535.htm

Answer (score 1):

If I'm correct the unicode 0 (NCHAR 0x0) does not count as a character but as a NULL (But not the SQL NULL type).
The wildcard _ is searching replacing 1 character which means the value need to have at least one character. Removing the _ will give you the desired result.